# circusctl incr <name> [<nbprocess>] does not increment by nbprocess

Tags: circusd

Here is my circus.ini

```
[circus]
check_delay = 5
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555
pubsub_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
stats_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5557
httpd = False
debug = False 

[watcher:sample1]
cmd = /worker/sample1.php
warmup_delay = 0 
numprocesses = 10 

[watcher:sample2]
cmd = /worker/sample2.php
warmup_delay = 0
numprocesses = 10

[plugin:flapping]
use = circus.plugins.flapping.Flapping
retry_in = 3
max_retry = 2
```

I am trying to increase the number of processes by 2(nbprocess) for `sample1`. I tried

```
circusctl incr sample1 2
```

But circus always increases it by 1, not by 2(nbprocess). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by the author. [Here](https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus/issues/421#issuecomment-18840840) is the reported bug.